# Disadvantages of having child first class loader?

Tags: java

I am developing application which loads different apps in different class loaders, so I am thinking to use child first class loader. To solve the problem like child apps have dependency on different version of class, that the main application uses. Is there any side effects using this approach? If yes can you suggest me the good approach to solve this problem?

Comment: Why don't you use OSGi?

Comment: For example `Tomcat` uses different class loader for each web application. You can do something like it.

Comment: Not only Tomcat; this is the standard approach for Java application containers generally.

Comment: @AdamArold ya i'll try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only side effects are:

- you will use more memory to store multiple versions of the class (shouldn't be a problem really)
- make sure your class instances never cross boundaries. If you load classfile A twice with two different classloaders, they are not compatible

For example:

```
A a = new A();   // from classloader1
System.out.println(a instanceof A)  // A from classloader2
```

This will print "false"

Comment: Yes. memory is not a problem, and anyway we can't avoid it. My only concern will it break anything?